# Perl: Easy way to rearrange MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: perl

Example input: 8/23/2008 (single digit day/month do not get leading zeros)

Desired output: 2008-08-23

Prefer to use perl. Thanks!

Comment: I knew how to rearrange the numbers but not how to add a leading zero to single digit days/months. I guess (seeing as I was voted down, boo) that I should have mentioned that but how complicated did I need to make my question?

Comment: Especially when someone else can bang it out in 2 minutes like jwodder did below?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display 4/25/10 to 2010-25-04?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699039/how-to-display-4-25-10-to-2010-25-04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sprintf '%3$04d-%02d-%02d', split m:/:, $inputDate
```

Comment: Fessing up: I --'d after trying this at the command line and failing to shell quote it properly so it seemed to fail but in fact it works. I owe you two ++s for teaching me something I didn't know -- "format parameter index" -- and for my being too fast to dismiss it because I didn't.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`DateTime::Format::Strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Strptime/) and [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/) (which everyone should have installed if they have to deal with dates or times in any way):

```
my $parser   = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%m/%d/%Y');
my $iso_date = $parser->parse_datetime('8/23/2008')->ymd('-');
```

Comment: I use DateTime for almost everything, but this is a tank to swat a fly.

Comment: @ikegami: You could say the same about using Perl for this :)

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't yet installed DateTime, you can use Time::Piece:

```
use Time::Piece;

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime('8/23/2008', '%m/%d/%Y');
print $t->strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),"\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
join '-', (split qr{/}, $_)[2,0,1]
```

- [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)
- [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)
- [list slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)

Comment: Don't you mean `join '-', (split '/', $_)[2,0,1];`? The indexes look off by one to me and there's no need to split on a regex when a single character will do the job. Also, this doesn't zero pad the month or day numbers.

Comment: @mu is too short, oops! fixed.

Comment: @mu is too short, As for your mention of regex patterns, it makes no sense. `split` only takes a regex pattern for input. `' '` is the only exception.

Comment: Right about the regex comment, my mistake, I get my languages confused sometimes. I think `printf('%4.4d-%2.2d-%2.2d', (split qr{/}, $_)[2,0,1])` would work better than the `join` though.