# How to display 4/25/10 to 2010-25-04?

Tags: perl, split, printf

```
my$str= '4/25/10';
my$sr = join(' ',split (/\//,$str));
#my$s = sprintf '%3$d %2$d %1$d',$srt;
print$sr,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
4 25 10
```

But i want output like `2010-25-04`.Can any one suggest me how display the my desire output.Give me your suggestion
you answers will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a braindead solution might be:

```
my @date = split( /\//,$str)
printf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $date[2] + 2000, $date[1], $date[0]);
```

You could write something a little more self-documenting by highlighting what you expect to be year, month and day like so:

```
my ($day, $month, $year) = split /\//, $str;
printf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $year + 2000, $month, $day);
```

Comment: thank you giving your answer but @JB answer little bit easy when compared to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're not that far off.

Instead of splitting and joining in a single operation, you can keep individual variables to handle the data better:

```
my ($d,$m,$y) = split /\//, $str;
```

Then you can format it in most any way you please, for example:

```
printf "20%02d-%02d-%02d\n", $y, $d, $m;
```

A few notes, though:

- I won't comment about the source format, but the format you're converting to doesn't make a lot of sense.  You'd probably be better using ISO-8601: 2010-04-25.
- Obviously, this way of doing only works up to year 2099.
- For anything more serious, you'd be better off delegating this kind of work to date handling modules. See for example [this question for parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486470/12274) and [this question for formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8288688/12274)

Comment: That would be a good time to accept the answer by clicking on the little check mark next to it, then ;-)

Comment: in your answer why you use `02`?please tell me

Comment: A leading zero induces zero-padding (prints 4 as 04).

Answer (score 1):

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%m/%d/%y',
    locale    => 'en_US'
);
my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime('4/25/10');
print $dt->strftime('%Y-%d-%m'), "\n";
```

*Gives:*

```
2010-25-04
```

Comment: what is meant by `use DateTime::Format::Strptime;` i don't about that because i'm still beginner.Can you explain what purpose of that?

Comment: you provide the input/output formats and it understand the date, does the conversion. This might be useful in case you need to handle various input/output formats, or switch timezone etc.

Comment: when i use your code it showing error like `can't locate dateTime/formates/strptcime.pm in @INC (@inc contain:./usr/local/lib64/perl5/usr/local/share/perl5/usr/lib64/perl5vendor_perl/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/usr/lib64/perl5/usr/share/perl5.).`

Comment: you have to install it through cpan. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-install-a-perl-module/

Comment: Can you tell me what is the use of `CPAN`

Comment: CPAN is a repository of Perl modules. Generally there is some module that already implements what you want so you install a module and use it.

Comment: majorly why we use this Perl modules in Perl scripting? how it help while writing Perl program?

Comment: This question is an example, the thing you want to do is already implemented and tested so instead of writing it yourself you use it.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do to DateTime for this. [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece) has been included with the Perl core distribution for years.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $date = '4/25/10';

my $date_tp = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%m/%d/%y');

say $date_tp->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: what is the use of `cpan`? how it helps while writing programs

Comment: CPAN is a repository of code libraries. It's extra (free) code that makes writing Perl programs easier. It helps because it gives you code that you don't need to write. But you don't need to know about CPAN for my solution as the library I use (Time::Piece) is already installed as part of your local copy of Perl.

Comment: can you tell me how to install this cpan modules

Comment: Many of them are pre-built for your system so you can install them with yum (for RedHat/Fedora/Centos systems), apt (for Debian/Ubuntu systems) or ppm (for Windows). Alternatively, there's [a good guide here](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html).